# lvm vgchange device-mapper reload ioctl on failed No data available

Tags: lvm

My LVM seems to be in an inconsistent state:

```
[~] # vgchange -a y                  
device-mapper: reload ioctl on (252:16) failed: No data available
device-mapper: reload ioctl on (252:16) failed: No data available
10 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1" now active
```

The RAID-5 (Linux Multiple Disks) has crashed and since the rebuild it cannot be activated anymore. What can I do.

Some diagnostic output, tell me if you need more information:

```
[~] # pvs -v --segments                   
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree Start  SSize   LV                      Start Type   PE Ranges             
  /dev/md1   vg1  lvm2 a--  21.80t    0       0   36864 lv544                       0 linear /dev/md1:0-36863      
  /dev/md1   vg1  lvm2 a--  21.80t    0   36864   16384 tp1_meta6                   0 linear /dev/md1:36864-53247  
  /dev/md1   vg1  lvm2 a--  21.80t    0   53248 5662624 [tp1_tierdata_2_fcorig]     0 linear /dev/md1:53248-5715871
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t      0   16384 tp1_meta1                   0 linear /dev/sdf:0-16383      
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t  16384   16384 tp1_meta2                   0 linear /dev/sdf:16384-32767  
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t  32768   16384 tp1_meta3                   0 linear /dev/sdf:32768-49151  
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t  49152   16384 tp1_meta4                   0 linear /dev/sdf:49152-65535  
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t  65536   16384 tp1_meta0                   0 linear /dev/sdf:65536-81919  
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t  81920   16384 tp1_meta5                   0 linear /dev/sdf:81920-98303  
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t  98304   16384 tp1_meta7                   0 linear /dev/sdf:98304-114687 
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t 114688   16384 [tp1_tmeta]                 0 linear /dev/sdf:114688-131071
  /dev/sdf   vg1  lvm2 a--   7.28t 6.78t 131072 1776649                             0 free

[~] # vgs -v
    Using volume group(s) on command line.
  VG   Attr   Ext   #PV #LV #SN VSize  VFree VG UUID                                VProfile
  vg1  wz--n- 4.00m   2  12   0 29.08t 6.78t 1VJkVt-vfPX-vBAv-KtuC-kKDU-1CDd-1RBuel

[~] # lvs -v
    Using logical volume(s) on command line.
    target_name:thin-pool
  LV        VG   #Seg Attr       LSize   Maj Min KMaj KMin Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Cpy%Sync Log Convert LV UUID                                LProfile
  lv1       vg1     1 Vwi---t---  21.00t  -1  -1   -1   -1 tp1                                                 TuCexj-MyZA-uIkX-kzVp-KBWt-dHVQ-Iq6t27         
  lv288     vg1     1 Vwi---t---   2.00t  -1  -1   -1   -1 tp1                                                 f0jKvz-Jm4G-JZ8l-8ysp-2RDS-cDWJ-Ue0VCR         
  lv544     vg1     1 -wi-a----- 144.00g  -1  -1  252    0                                                     SHXwIE-iAMG-5ctO-g0RG-55P9-jeke-df3S4n         
  tp1       vg1     1 twi-aot---  21.60t  -1  -1  252    6             0.00   0.02                             Hk25P5-gQkc-pJHw-jKfL-U9cB-2vBF-74lr2L         
  tp1_meta0 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252    8                                                     foHo1k-gciB-VJcM-9CRV-ySC0-0I9A-rshk3A         
  tp1_meta1 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252    9                                                     8bloJL-stWn-1O3r-j5jQ-vlqv-DpNe-waeIef         
  tp1_meta2 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252   10                                                     AvXCmL-zVIg-xTCm-ZtOz-1VGT-EEBU-cugNA8         
  tp1_meta3 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252   11                                                     EVcMvv-S0BC-N0Xh-5Pzj-3Rrj-RkFb-ZTgMw8         
  tp1_meta4 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252   12                                                     YCgXIz-eZxy-N2Wz-8Exl-9dJw-syIb-dVeux4         
  tp1_meta5 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252   13                                                     H35ozg-XyJ3-rjPP-ipTz-DIDV-JNPA-fSg54E         
  tp1_meta6 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252   14                                                     fl5ACi-7uNv-h5Fw-71NI-G8nT-93sz-VgMdR5         
  tp1_meta7 vg1     1 -wi-a-----  64.00g  -1  -1  252   15                                                     ap8Nds-GACe-9dXu-BZ6J-H1df-HwOc-pQ7VnX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While searching for a solution I found this thread: https://charles-gagnon.medium.com/repair-a-thin-pool-a42f41169541. Unfortunately the thread was not really helpful for me because my issue was not solvable with the explained steps but the author mentioned [Ming-Hung Tsai](https://github.com/mingnus) which helped him. So I also contacted him and the helped me with this issue:

First of all you have to understand the basic structure and case of my issue:

I have a volume group **vg1** which is on **/dev/md1**:

```
[~] # pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md1
  VG Name               vg1
  PV Size               21.80 TiB / not usable 2.50 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5715872
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          5715872
  PV UUID               C6femQ-nMRN-d8F0-f2pk-BRVA-pQuH-Dv3skX
```

In this volume group are a lot of logical volume but the problematic logical volume was **tp1**:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                tp1
  VG Name                vg1
  LV UUID                Hk25P5-gQkc-pJHw-jKfL-U9cB-2vBF-74lr2L
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time MAML-NAS01, 2021-08-03 13:01:08 +0200
  LV Pool metadata       tp1_tmeta
  LV Pool data           tp1_tierdata_0
  LV Status              available
  # open                 3
  LV Size                21.60 TiB
  Allocated pool data    32.45%
  Allocated pool chunks  14697037
  Allocated metadata     0.69%
  Current LE             5662224
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     4096
  Block device           252:6
```

This logical volume is not a simple chunk of data which is stored inside the volume group. It is a thin provisioned space which is dynamically filling a defined area of the volume group. Inside this thin provisioned space you can create logical volumes (in my case **lv1** and **lv288**). Such a thin provisioned space is build with two logical volumes: **tp1_tmeta** and **tp1_tierdata_0**. One logical volume is for the data and the other is for storing the logical structure.

In my case the RAID-5 is crashed (**/dev/md1**) and thereby also the **tp1_tmeta** logical volume.

The first step is to create a dump of the metadata (this file will be around 100MB). Please note that the metadata snapshot offset 8388565 is specific to QNAP LVM:

```
thin_dump /dev/mapper/vg1-tp1_meta0 --metadata-snap=8388565 -o dump.txt
```

Note the metadata-snap command line argument: The metadata pool does cyclic snapshots. When your pool crahses you rollback to such snapshots.

In the second step you restore this pool:

```
/sbin/pdata_tools thin_restore -i dump.txt -o /dev/mapper/vg1-tp1_meta6
```

In my case I have restored it to **vg1-tp1_meta6** because this was the only metadata pool which was on **/dev/md1** (see my question).

Then you have to tell the tp1 that this is now the poolmetadata:

```
lvconvert vg1/tp1 --poolmetadata vg1/tp1_meta6
lvconvert --thinpool vg1/tp1 --poolmetadata vg1/tp1_meta6
lvconvert vg1/tp1 --swapmetadata --poolmetadata vg1/tp1_meta6
lvconvert --type tier-thin-pool --thinpool vg1/tp1 --poolmetadata vg1/tp1_meta6
```

After that the **vg1-tp1_meta6** logical volume will be bound to the tp1 and hidden. Now you should be able to activate the thin logical volume and its inner logical volumes.

In my case the repair command, which is often mentioned in other threads, created, each time I called it, another metadata device for reparation, but then crashed because it was impossible, in my case to repair the metadata (without rollback). Thereby I had to remove **/dev/sdf** from my volume group:

```
vgsplit vg1 vg2 /dev/sdf
```

After in my case also the inner logical volumes were damaged. The logical volumes lv1 and lv288 were formatted with ext4 where I had to do a filesystem check. Use e2fsck_64 to do filesystem check.